# working 'java -cp' not working all of a sudden in ubuntu

Tags: java, class, runtime, classpath, java-runtime-compiler

We have the below java command which was running and stopped working all of a sudden,

java –cp "classes:lib/*" xxx.yyy.ppp

The jar is within lib directory and the jar contains the class.
It stopped working all of a sudden and gived the below error,

"Error: Could not find or load main class –cp"

Why is it considering '-cp' as the main class, even though ppp (example) has the main class. Please help me out with this...

Comment: `–cp` should be `-cp`.

Comment: In your title you are using *-* while in the text of your question you are using *–*. *–* is not the default hyphen character, did you maybe copy and paste it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a default hypen before cp  as `java –cp "classes:lib/*" xxx.yyy.ppp`

Use this instead : `java -cp "classes:lib/*" xxx.yyy.ppp`

Comment: True, i copied the comand which the team was using. Thanks. But how on earth that hyphen can come?

Comment: @SijoKurien I suspect someone pasted the command into a word processor, which “helpfully” turned the ASCII hyphen into a dash, and then you copied it from that word processing document.

Comment: It may be some kind of special formatted character. I am not sure, may be while copying it got converted to that. From where did you copy ? Internet or some files ?

Comment: yes, my team member copied from a word document